# file-name encoding problems

Tags: linux, ntfs, encoding, ext3, utf-8

I googled over this topic but couldn't find what I was looking for... the following "happend" to me:

I had my files stored on a NTFS-USB Harddisk, because of space problems I moved them to an ext3 system....somehow the filename (content is still ok as far as I saw) encoding screwed up....my files look like the following now:

```
KkÃ¼ken <--- should have an "ü"
JÃ¤ger <--- should be an "ä"
ZwÃ¶lf <--- should be an "ö"
fÃ¼nfte <-- should be an "ü"
etc ....
```

These are just examples, but already give me my first question
Why has the "ü" two different representations?
(Maybe I screw up, before I screw up and now I have a mixing of x different encoding-layers? :) )

I tried the following command:

```
convmv -r -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1  *
```

This command work for some files (for example `ZwÃ¶lf`) but not for all:

```
iso-8859-1 doesn't cover all needed characters for: "fÃ¼nfte"
```

So Iguess it must be another encoding - but which? How can I find out this?

And is there any way that I can still fix all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy and paste the 4 lines into a text file, then open it in firefox. the Browser auto detect it to be UTF-8 and display following

```
Kküken <--- should have an "�"
Jäger <--- should be an "�"
Zwölf <--- should be an "�"
fünfte <-- should be an "�"
```

Your original copy did not "screw up", it pickup NTFS unicode file name correctly. Instead it seems your display/tty/font does not support UTF8/unicode output.

Maybe try to look at your copy in X windows environment.

Comment: thought of that too, I'm accessin primary via samba share with a windows 8 /windows 7 machine, there the special chars are mostly replaced with "_" :S

Comment: I apology for my stupidity, I realized just now that you weren't talking about windwos, but about x. So I installed xfe (didn't have anything installed because I dont need it) and you were absolutely right, there everything is perfect! So i changed my putty use utf8 and now there its fine too. What's left now: Samba, I guess there is also a setting for that... and another problem is that my dlna software (which is installed on the same machine) can't read the files with the "special chars"...

Comment: and my third and last answer, I set "unix charset = UTF-8" in the samba config...everything seems fine now. Thank you!